# simple math: finding what percentage B is performing when compared to A

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Boy A's performance is $500$ and boy B's performance is $525$ for a particular task.

How can we calculate how much percentage B is performing better than A?

Comment: So, in $500$ the positive difference is $525-500=25,$ what will be in $100?$

Comment: But why 'divisibility'?

Comment: i didnt find any other option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentage at which B is performing better than A is given by:
$$\dfrac{(\text{B's performance}) - (\text{A's performance})}{\text{A's performance}}\times 100\%$$

In this case, that means that B performs 
$\quad \dfrac{525 - 500}{500}\times 100\%\quad$
better than A.

Comment: @Amzoti I agree! There has been a dramatic "downswing" in acks from the community at large. Perhaps the volume of questions plays a roll, but even this year (indeed, within the last few months), I've witnessed a down-swing.